# Cannot compile c++ file with glfw with conan on m1 mac

Tags: c++, glfw, apple-m1, conan

I tried to create a window in c++ with OpenGL and glfw with conan package manager on m1 mac. But I couldn't compile the source file.

Using librarys:

- OpenGL
- glfw

Using build tools:

- conan
- cmake
- ninja

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    if (glfwInit() == GLFW_FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Cannot initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

    int width = 1260;
    int height = 960;
    std::string title = "opengl-demo";
    GLFWwindow *const window(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL));
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Cannot create GLFW Window!";
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwShowWindow(window);

    for (int i=0;i<1000000;i++){}

    glfwTerminate();
    glfwSetErrorCallback(NULL);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
}
```

conanfile.txt

```yaml
[requires]
glfw/3.3.6

[generators]
cmake
```

error message:

```
$ ninja
FAILED: bin/opengl-demo
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/opengl-demo.dir/src/main.cpp.o -o bin/opengl-demo -L/Users/*<user name>*/.conan/data/glfw/3.3.6/_/_/package/24b3a23034248276e5247366e59252156cd95f1e/lib  && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      Window::Window(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwDefaultWindowHints", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      Window::~Window() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      Window::Window(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetErrorCallback", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSwapInterval", referenced from:
      Window::Window(int, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowHint", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(opengl-by-glfw)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(opengl-by-glfw src/main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

repository: https://github.com/javaboy-github/opengl-by-glfw

I googled [this issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1805) but I don't know how to do it with conan. Please help me!

Edit: I changed CMakeLists.txt according to below comments.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(opengl-by-glfw)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

add_definitions("-std=c++11")

if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
  message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
  file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/v0.16.1/conan.cmake"
                "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake"
                EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=396e16d0f5eabdc6a14afddbcfff62a54a7ee75c6da23f32f7a31bc85db23484
                TLS_VERIFY ON)
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)


conan_cmake_autodetect(settings)

conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt
                BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS
                BUILD missing
                ARCH armv8
                ) # setting for m1 mac

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(opengl-by-glfw src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(opengl-by-glfw OpenGL::GL)
target_link_libraries(opengl-by-glfw CONAN_PKG::glfw)
target_link_libraries(opengl-by-glfw CONAN_PKG::glm)
```

But another error such as below happened.

```
FAILED: bin/opengl-by-glfw
: && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/opengl-by-glfw.dir/src/main.cpp.o -o bin/opengl-by-glfw  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/OpenGL.tbd  -lglfw3  -framework  Cocoa  -framework  IOKit  -framework  CoreFoundation  -framework  OpenGL  /Users/*<user name>*/.conan/data/glfw/3.3.6/_/_/package/24b3a23034248276e5247366e59252156cd95f1e/lib/libglfw3.a  -framework  Cocoa  -framework  IOKit  -framework  CoreFoundation  -framework  OpenGL && :
ld: library not found for -lglfw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: How are you linking to the libraries? Please show a [mre] including your cmake files. The library directory is in your command line but not the library itself

Comment: Thanks. I added  CMakeLists.txt and a link to the repository.

Comment: `find_package` doesn't do anything on it's own, you need to link to the found package, e.g. `target_link_library(opengl-by-glfw OpenGL::GL)`. You need to link to `glfw` too, I'd recommend using the [cmake conan wrapper](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan) to make that easier and setting `CMAKE_TARGETS`

Comment: How should I use `conan_cmake_run`? I did 
`conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS BUILD missing ARCH armv8)`.
But an err happened `fatal error: 'GLFW/glfw3.h' file not found` when i execute ninja.

Comment: You need to link to `CONAN_PKG::glfw` https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan#cmake_targets

Comment: Thanks. I added some code according to your advice. But another error happened. I added it to my question.

Comment: `${CONAN_LIBS}` isn't necessary, might be the origin of the stray`-lglfw3`? Might be worth cleaning your cmake cache too (easiest way is to delete the build directory)

Comment: Thanks. The program got able to run! If you write an answer, I'll select it as the best answer.